# Maven Oracle artifacts pom dependencies configuration

Tags: java, maven, weblogic12c

I have a Java maven project on which I'm currently working on that requires an Oracle weblogic dependency for Weblogic full client (wlfullclient.jar).

I know that there is a brand new Oracle Maven repository (that is in fact already proxied by our Nexus) but unfortunately it is not browsable.

Where can I find the right dependency information in order to insert it in my project pom in terms of GAV parameters (Group ID, Artifact, Version)?
Is this information published anywhere?

At the moment, as a temporary workaround, I got this library from the Oracle Weblogic 12c server and put in into a 3rd party hosted repository on my Nexus.

Comment: Is this: [Configuring the WebLogic Development Maven Plug-In](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm) what are you looking for ?

Comment: Thanks Edi for your comment, but I would need, in general, a browsable repository index that can give information not only about the jar I'm searching but all the Oracle dependencies I might use.

Comment: What about Running the [Oracle Maven Synchronization Plug-In](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN310)? Depending on the dependencies really, some I had to manually install myself in my local repo but I had a non-commun scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find a [site](https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/oracle/) which mirrors Oracle Maven index, so I've been able to find out the right dependencies GAV parameters I have to use in my poms.
A couple of examples:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Notice that this index site seems quite up-to-date since it contains artifacts pertaining to version 12.1.0.2 and some of them have been updated on September 14th.

Comment: now it's mandatory to register first at https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/application/maven/index.html more details at: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9012

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are not having a browser viewable list - https://community.oracle.com/thread/3650312 .

Answer (score 0):

you should use repository browser provided by Netbeans. See here
https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/oracle_maven_repository_index_now